# Confluent Sink Connector - Sink to Multiple Database Destinations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

If I need to copy the same data from a topic to multiple databases with different IPs, do I need to create multiple sink connectors or I can somehow specify multiple destinations in connection.url or some other way.

Your help is most appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about Kafka Connect and the [JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector)? If so, then you need to create one sink connector per target database. One connector cannot target multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spin up the individual sink connectors sink since the connector class or the configuration that is being used varies with databases. Specifying multiple destination IPs of different databases in the `connection.url` won't work.